# kubectl substring match using go-template

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, go-templates

I am trying to find a way to match a substring in the `go-template` in `kubectl`. I am only able to find operators like those listed below, however, none of them is to match a substring between LHS and RHS. See Example below:

```
eq
    Returns the boolean truth of arg1 == arg2
ne
    Returns the boolean truth of arg1 != arg2
lt
    Returns the boolean truth of arg1 < arg2
le
    Returns the boolean truth of arg1 <= arg2
gt
    Returns the boolean truth of arg1 > arg2
ge
    Returns the boolean truth of arg1 >= arg2
```

Example problem: (**its dumb downed for simplicity**, I know there are other way to do this using `jsonpath`, etc. But the focus is on `go-template` for solving the real isssue).

My Pod list:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS        AGE
default       test-pod                                           1/1     Running     9 (4h6m ago)    8d
default       web-dev                                            0/3     Completed   0               5h23m
default       web-test                                           2/2     Running     0               3h7m
kube-system   coredns-76b4fb4578-2v42x                           1/1     Running     26 (4h6m ago)   22d
kube-system   coredns-76b4fb4578-s567x                           1/1     Running     10 (4h6m ago)   10d
kube-system   dns-autoscaler-7979fb6659-c2wfb                    1/1     Running     14 (4h6m ago)   14d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kube-master                         1/1     Running     12 (4h6m ago)   10d
```

Now I can filter the pods present in the default namespace, using `eq` operator.

```
kubectl get pod -A -o go-template='{{range $i,$p := .items}}{{ if (eq $p.metadata.namespace "default")}}{{ $p.metadata.name }} {{.metadata.namespace}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}'
test-pod default
web-dev default
web-test default
```

**The problem:** What if I want to match the pods present in a namespace with the `def` string present in it? How can I use a substring match or regex match? Or someone says authoritatively(with reference to documentation) that it's not possible using `go-template`.

Note: The example problem above, is a dumb version of the issue, not the real issue. The idea is to find if `go-template` provides any option for substring match with kubectl.

Comment: Are you determined to do this entirely using `kubectl`? Something like `jq` has a much richer query syntax, so piping JSON output from `kubectl` to `jq` would give you much more flexibility.

Comment: @larsks I am aware that for a problem like this, tools like `jq` are preferred. I would most likely use `jq`, `JSON path`, `awk` etc. to get the result.  The above question came to me while ***learning*** about `go-template`, it's likely that the expected behavior in the question is impossible with `go-template`, but unfortunately, there is no clear documentation.  I am hoping someone authoritatively(with reference) says, it's not possible.

Comment: I think you cannot do it with the `go-template` in-built function list. You can find the various in-built functions listed here https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Functions .  One more thing, about documentation, in my opinion, *I think anyone, including tool, software, language, etc is supposed to tell "what their product is supposed to do OR capable to do", but not liable to tell what it cannot. Although, it's good to have*.

Comment: ***Oversimplified example: *** Eg: `notepad` cannot edit photos, you will not find any documentation in notepad saying it cannot edit images. Although, it will tell what it can do with the text.

Comment: You won't be able to do this using the built-in operators.  If you were using go-template directly, you'd be able to create your own function which you'd be able to use.  But since you are using kubectl, you are limited to the built-ins.

Comment: Technically you can (I did not try it out) do a messy workaround: iterate over items - as you did. In the loop create another one that would generate substrings of a certain length (equal to the other stream you're looking for a match). If you'll have any match you can use break in inner loop.

Comment: @Armatorix I thought this way but have not found the way to iterate through string to make substrings. Go template doesn't support general iteration like string or counter